# want to receive a message packet at server send by client.... in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

```
    /* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <unistd.h>
     #include <sys/types.h> 
     #include <sys/socket.h>
     #include <netinet/in.h>



void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}










======>>>now client code


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

//im novice, so please ignore silly way to ask

this code is to get simple string over n/w. now i want to get a predefined kind standard message to be sent and receive, for that i have to define a structure,

Now my question is how can i sent and get a structure over n/w in C-language. plzzzz help me.
**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

well, look at write prototype:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

the second argument is a generic void pointer, so you can send whatever you want. put there the address of the structure you want to transmit and its size.

There also the endiannes to be considered (little vs big endian). If the machines that are communicating have different endianness then this approach doesn't work. Have a look at those [conversion functions](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) like htons,ntohs, ...

If the data structure you want to send store your primitive types using machine byte order, sending the whole structure don't work. You should store each value in network order, for example:

```
struct foo{
   uint32_t a;
   uint16_t b;
}foo; 

foo f;
f.a = htonl(10);
f.b = htons(5);

write(fd, (void *)&f, sizeof(foo));
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that with this approach, it is your responsibility to ensure that structure padding is identical on both ends of the connection. This may be an issue if the server and the client use different compilers and/or operating systems. Similarly, endianness may require attention too.

Comment: @aix: i fixed my answer. please check it and tell me if you see any error.